# How to list residual config files for removed packages?

Tags: apt, purge

I've noticed a ton of packages with the `residual-config` status in the `apt list` and before deleting them I'd like to make sure it will not delete any important information, how can I show the list of files that will be deleted?

Comment: Re. "how can I show the list of files that will be deleted?" Please add the command you intend using to perform the deletion.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help, but I've already found the answer, just posted it here to share. Unfortunately, I still can't mark it as answered for 2 days.

Comment: But there is still room for improvement. You can try writing a script that concatenates all the relevant postrm scripts, for example. As for the command: I usually use `apt-get purge`.

Comment: When I run `apt list`, I just get a list of packages like this: package_name/version/(amd64|i386|all). No mention of the status. How do you get that with `apt list`? I can get the same information using `dpkg --list | grep ^rc`.

Comment: It just lists all available packages, at least with `apt 1.0.10.2ubuntu1` this should show you all packages with a status: `apt list | grep "\[.*\]"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see what will be removed you'll have to check the corresponding postrm script, as in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/packagename.postrm`

From `man dpkg` (shortened):

> Note: some configuration files might be unknown to dpkg because they are created and handled separately through the configuration scripts. In that case the package's **postrm** script has to take care of their removal. This only applies to files in system directories.
>
> Purging of a package consists of:
>
> 1. Removing the package.
> 2. **Running postrm script.**

Comment: Might be worth adding the following command to this answer:  `for i in $(dpkg --list | awk '{if ($1 == "rc") {print $2}}'); do if [ ! -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/$i.postrm ]; then  sudo apt-get purge -y $i; fi;  done`

Comment: It filters out all the packages that are in `rc` status, but *don't* have a `postrm` script (and hence do nothing).  (I've just removed 20 or so such packages).

Answer (score 8):

Here is a one-liner to show you all packages with residual configuration files and a list of said files per package:

```bash
apt-cache show '?config-files' | grep -oP '^Package: \K(.*)$' | uniq | xargs -I '0' dpkg-query -W --showformat "\${binary:Package}:\n\${db-fsys:Files}" '0'
```

Example output:

```
postgresql-13:
postgresql-common:
 /etc
 /etc/init.d
 /etc/init.d/postgresql
 /etc/logrotate.d
 /etc/logrotate.d/postgresql-common
 /etc/postgresql
 /etc/sysctl.d
 /etc/sysctl.d/30-postgresql-shm.conf
 /var
 /var/lib
 /var/lib/postgresql
 /var/log
 /var/log/postgresql
```

Explanation:

- `apt-cache show '?config-files'`: Show obsolete config files as per [apt search patterns](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/apt-patterns.7.html).
- `grep -oP '^Package: \K(.*)$' | uniq`: filter package names and remove duplicate outputs from the previous step.
- `xargs -I '0' dpkg-query -W --showformat "\${binary:Package}:\n\${db-fsys:Files}" '0'`: forward the package names to `dpkg-query` and print the fields `Package` (the package name) and a special `db-fsys:Files` field which lists all installed files from that package currently on your system.

Note: you can also purge your system of all residual configuration files using the command:

```bash
sudo apt purge '?config-files'
```

This doesn't touch installed packages, but I advise caution.

**WARNING**: `apt purge '?config-files'` **CAN DELETE ARBITRARY THINGS YOU DON'T EXPECT.** Please be careful when using it and make backups of your important data first (databases, credentials, etc). Try using `--dry-run` first if you're unsure.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer. Unfortunately, I cannot mark it as the main accepted, at least not yet. There are files mentioned in postrm scripts that are not in the `db-fsys:Files` For example, I checked the `tor` package and the postrm contains `rm -f "/etc/apparmor.d/disable/system_tor"` while it's not in the `dpkg-query -W --showformat "\${binary:Package}:\n\${db-fsys:Files}" tor`. Or is it expected?

Comment: @int_ua You're welcome, and that's the expected behaviour since anything not explicitly installed by the .deb package is something that apt doesn't know about, but it gives you a general idea of where to look since most packages will explicitly create their configuration directories upon installation using this method.

Comment: Thank you so much! One quick note: some packages may not show up with configuration files. In my example, I had LXD installed and I was uncertain about the effects of the suggested action to remove the package. I went to https://packages.ubuntu.com/ searched for the package, and after a bit of more research (switching between past releases), guessing, and looking at the output of snap list I felt confident that it became a transitional package and the functionality is now provided by a snap, thus the package was indeed safe to remove.

Comment: Do back up everything before running `apt purge '?config-files'`; it erased my maria database!

Comment: @Lamp yep. It's a terrible design imo. They should add a `'?data-files'` or something for treating things like that separately from config files. I'll add a warning to the answer.

Comment: `--dry-run` doesn't really help. It only lists the packages, not the files. Meanwhile most packages are gong to show `/etc` in that list, but (hopefully) aren't going to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Combining answers from [@voodooattack](https://askubuntu.com/users/220164/voodooattack) and [@int_ua](https://askubuntu.com/users/20275/int-ua)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -eo pipefail

apt-cache show '?config-files' | grep -oP '^Package: \K(.*)$' | uniq | while read -r pkg; do
    dpkg-query -W --showformat "\${binary:Package}:\n\${db-fsys:Files}" "${pkg}"
    if [[ -e /var/lib/dpkg/info/${pkg}.postrm ]]; then
        echo " postrm:"
        sed 's/^/  /' /var/lib/dpkg/info/${pkg}.postrm
    fi
done
```

Example output on my system:

```
$ apt-list-residual-files.sh 
libatk-adaptor:amd64:
 /etc
 /etc/X11
 /etc/X11/Xsession.d
 /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90atk-adaptor
 /etc/environment.d
 /etc/environment.d/90atk-adaptor.conf
xbrlapi:
 /etc
 /etc/X11
 /etc/X11/Xsession.d
 /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90xbrlapi
 postrm:
  #!/bin/sh
  set -e
  # Automatically added by dh_installdeb/13.11.6ubuntu1
  dpkg-maintscript-helper rm_conffile /etc/X11/Xsession.d/60xbrlapi 6.1\+dfsg-2\~ xbrlapi -- "$@"
  # End automatically added section
```